# Why does this cat picture trigger a Facebook warning about violent/graphic content?

Tags: facebook

Facebook systems claim that [this picture](https://www.facebook.com/Zerquix18/photos/a.432207806826334/1864322060281561/?type=3&theater) may contain violent or graphic content.

[image]

(When opening the link, Facebook asks you to login. I suppose it's because Facebook considers the image offensive and hides it from people haven't logged in).

Here's how it looks before you click on "Uncover photo":

[image]

Compressing the picture doesn't seem to fix the issue.

What's really happening under the hood?

Someone told me that the picture was altered at the pixel level, yet I haven't been able to find any explanation online. Is it a simple Facebook bug or someone managed to trick the system?

Comment: You should post the image in your question. When I click on the link, it asks me to login or create an account. Also, I'm not sure this is the best stack exchange site for this question. Maybe [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) would be better? (Not sure - read their help section to find out for sure.)

Comment: @user1118321 Apparently, Facebook hides that post because it thinks the post is offensive. Any other post from the same page is public.

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting you just put the image into your post here. Just click the "edit" button, then click the picture button (looks like a framed picture of a mountain and sun), and choose the image  from your hard drive.

Comment: @user1118321 Added the picture and a screenshot of how it looks after you open the link. Thank you! Might consider moving the question to another community if this isn't the right one.

Comment: My guess is an AI identifies *potentially* offensive posts and a human moderator decides whether or not it is.  This eliminates most AI type errors, but sometimes humans err.  My guess is the moderator reviewing this image accidentally clicked on the button indicating that, in fact, it *was* offensive.  This rarely happens though.

Answer (score 6):

Probably because [machine learning systems are not infallible](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-8-how-to-intentionally-trick-neural-networks-b55da32b7196). The linked article describe how they were able to alter a few bits in a cat picture and got a neural network image recognition system to identify it as a teapot.

Comment: [This article](https://www.wired.com/story/researcher-fooled-a-google-ai-into-thinking-a-rifle-was-a-helicopter/) is great for explaining this. It neatly shows how such ML systems can be fooled into thinking an image of a pair of skiers on a mountain is an image of a dog.